# getting shift/reduce errors in my grammar

Tags: c, compiler-construction, yacc, lex

This is the part of grammar for my programming language. I am getting shift/reduce conflicts while compiling.

```
Rule 1:    encryption_spec: key_spec 

Rule 2:   key_spec:
    key_spec key_spec_content
    | key_spec_content
    ;

Rule 3:    key_spec_content: TOK_PROTECT key_keyowner 
    |TOK_PROTECT key_keyname
    |TOK_PROTECT key_keymethod
    |TOK_PROTECT key_pub_key
    |TOK_COMMA key_keyowner 
    |TOK_COMMA key_keyname
    |TOK_COMMA key_keymethod
    |TOK_COMMA key_pub_key
    |encoding
    ;
```

I am getting shift/reduce conflict in Rule 1.
Can you please suggest me something to modify ?

Comment: Look at the `y.output` file from `yacc -v` to see what the actual conflict is -- you need to look at what state the conflict is in and how the parser gets to that state to resolve it.

Comment: It is clear from the y.output that reason of conflict is:The grammar is not able to decide whether to keep looking or declare the encryption_spec block occurrence by Rule 1 after finding at least one of the statements by Rule 3

Comment: Then there is some other rule that can follow `encryption_spec`, not shown in your snippet above, that is the source of the conflict.

Comment: FWIW, SHIFT/REDUCE is not necessarily an error in your grammar. It is merely an ambiguity that you can program around in YACC. That is not to say you don't have an error in your grammar, but I don't know what you are trying to do. REDUCE/REDUCE is what you have to watch out for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `key_spec` rule is malformed. Indeed you have an infinite recursion.
You should change it for something like

```
key_spec: /* Empty. */
    | key_spec key_spec_content
;
```

EDIT: Remove the `%empty` bison extension.

Comment: Note that `%empty` is a bison extension for making epsilon rules more visible.  For normal yacc, you need an empty rule (nothing between the `:` and `|` except whitespace)

Comment: That was a typo.I know that was a infinite recursion.I am still getting a shift reduce/conflict in Rule 1.Any alternative for the grammar ?

Comment: First: can you edit your original post to fix the typo please? Second: without seeing your other non-terminals rules, I can't help you. Writing this program and putting `key_*` and `encoding` as terminals does not warn for any conflicts.

Comment: @LéoErcolanelli That was my bad ! Can you please suggest something regarding this problem ? I think the reason of conflict is:The grammar is not able to decide whether to extend or declare the encryption_spec block occurrence by Rule 1 after finding at least one of the statements by Rule 3.

Comment: @AnkurGautam The problem is not in the snippet you gave us. This gist is as much as I can test to reproduce your shift-reduce conflict, and it gives me none. https://gist.github.com/ercolanelli-leo/88a7dca033cee9264912
Feel free to modify it or comment it to add missing rules!

Answer (score 1):

The rule by @Leo is not correct because it allows zero occurrences of key_spec_content where the original requires at least one. The following should do this:

```
key_spec:
  key_spec key_spec_content
  | key_spec_content
;
```

However, this rule has an unnecessary  recursion. The following should be better:

```
key_spec:
  key_spec_content key_spec
  | key_spec_content
;
```

This allows to reduce after seeing each key_spec_content.

Comment: I agree for the empty rule. However you are wrong on left vs right recursion. Indeed, the left recursion DO reduce at each key_spec_content, no the right one. http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Recursion.html

Comment: The original requires an infinite number of `key_spec_content` and disallows any finite number.  So you need to change it to allow finite inputs, and the choice between allowing 0 or more and 1 or more seems arbitrary.

Comment: That was a typo.I know that was a infinite recursion.I am still getting a shift reduce/conflict in Rule 1.Any alternative for the grammar ?